# OpenAI Gym: How do I access environment registration data (for e.g. max_episode_steps) from within a custom OPenvironment?

Tags: machine-learning, reinforcement-learning, openai-gym

I created a custom environment using OpenAI Gym. I want to have access to the max_episode_steps and reward_threshold that are specified in ***init.py***
For eg:

```
from gym.envs.registration import registry, register, make, spec
register(
    id='myenv-v0',
    entry_point='gym.envs.algorithmic:myenv',
    tags={'wrapper_config.TimeLimit.max_episode_steps': 200},
    reward_threshold=25.0,
)
```

But how do I access this from ***gym_myenv.py***?
If I first create the environment and use env._max_episode_steps, I have access. However, I don't have access to ***_max_episode_steps*** from within ***gym_myenv.py***.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [pointed out by the Gymnasium team](https://github.com/Farama-Foundation/Gymnasium/issues/615), the `max_episode_steps` parameter is not passed to the base environment on purpose. We can, however, use a simple [Gymnasium wrapper](https://gymnasium.farama.org/api/wrappers/) to inject it into the base environment:

```py
"""This file contains a small gymnasium wrapper that injects the `max_episode_steps`
argument of a potentially nested `TimeLimit` wrapper into the base environment under the
`_time_limit_max_episode_steps` attribute.
"""
import gymnasium as gym


def get_time_limit_wrapper_max_episode_steps(env):
    """Returns the ``max_episode_steps`` attribute of a potentially nested
    ``TimeLimit`` wrapper.

    Args:
        env (gym.Env): The gymnasium environment.

    Returns:
        int: The value of the ``max_episode_steps`` attribute of a potentially nested
            ``TimeLimit`` wrapper. If the environment is not wrapped in a ``TimeLimit``
            wrapper, then this function returns ``None``.
    """
    if hasattr(env, "env"):
        if isinstance(env, gym.wrappers.TimeLimit):
            return env._max_episode_steps
        get_time_limit_wrapper_max_episode_steps(env.env)
    return None


def inject_attribute_into_base_env(env, attribute_name, attribute_value):
    """Injects the ``max_episode_steps`` argument into the base environment under the
    `_time_limit_max_episode_steps` attribute.

    Args:
        env (gym.Env): The gymnasium environment.
        attribute_name (str): The attribute's name to inject into the base
            environment.
        attribute_value (object): The attribute's value to inject into the base
            environment.
    """
    if hasattr(env, "env"):
        return inject_attribute_into_base_env(env.env, attribute_name, attribute_value)
    setattr(env, attribute_name, attribute_value)


class MaxEpisodeStepsInjectionWrapper(gym.Wrapper):
    """A gymnasium wrapper that injects the ``max_episode_steps`` attribute of the
    ``TimeLimit`` wrapper into the base environment as the
    ``_time_limit_max_episode_steps`` attribute. If the environment is not wrapped in
    a ``TimeLimit`` wrapper, then the ``_time_limit_max_episode_steps`` attribute is
    set to ``None``.
    """
    def __init__(self, env):
        """Wrap a gymnasium environment.
        Args:
            env (gym.Env): The gymnasium environment.
        """
        super().__init__(env)

        # Retrieve max_episode_steps from potentially nested TimeLimit wrappers.
        max_episode_steps = get_time_limit_wrapper_max_episode_steps(self.env)

        # Inject the max_episode_steps attribute into the base environment.
        inject_attribute_into_base_env(
            self.env, "_time_limit_max_episode_steps", max_episode_steps
        )
```

This wrapper can then be specified through the [additional_wrappers parameter of the gym.register](https://gymnasium.farama.org/api/registry/#gymnasium.register) method:

```py
import gymnasium as gym
from MY_PACKAGE.max_episode_steps_injection_wrapper import MaxEpisodeStepsInjectionWrapper

gym.register(
        id="ENV_ID",
        entry_point="ENV_ENTRY_POINT",
        max_episode_steps="MAX_EPISODE_STEPS",
        additional_wrappers=(MaxEpisodeStepsInjectionWrapper.wrapper_spec(),)
)
```

Answer (score 4):

It seems the only way to do this currently is to access them outside the **init** method that is after the gym environment object has been created i.e in any other method like reset() or render() or others.

It can be accessed either using `self.spec.max_episode_steps` or `self._max_episode_steps`

I am not sure whether it was intended to be like this or could it be a bug.

Answer (score 1):

If you see the code for `make()` here:

https://github.com/openai/gym/blob/c33cfd8b2cc8cac6c346bc2182cd568ef33b8821/gym/envs/registration.py#L76

the `Environment` is instantiated before the `spec` is made its property. I think the `max_timesteps` is not the environment's intrinsic property and the intent is to have the environment have any number of possible `max_timesteps` for the various environment IDs you may register for the same base environment.

By the way, if you see line 51 in that file, the tag you gave above wouldn't work because the value is overridden by the value you pass for `max_episode_steps` to `register()`. I tested it just now.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I was able to find a way around using max_timesteps in my code.

Answer (score 1):

This is how you access the `EnvSpec` of a given environment by name:

```py
>>> spec = gym.envs.registration.spec('CartPole-v0')
>>> spec
EnvSpec(CartPole-v0)
```

According to [the source](https://github.com/openai/gym/blob/ca42b052437c13da3a84d06c3748033e24cd2d42/gym/envs/registration.py#L63). the `kwargs` passed to the env's constructor should be stored in `spec._kwargs`.

I was just trying to find out how to get the `reward_threshold`, which is another example of a thing you can get from the spec:

```py
>>> spec.reward_threshold
195.0
```

You can also access the spec of an environment via `env.spec`.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).